# Installing windows to dual-boot

Tags: windows, windows-xp, multi-boot

I'm looking to install 32-bit windows with IIS to dual-boot with my 64-bit edition of windows on a laptop. I have a ten gig partition on my harddrive - is this large enough for a simple Windows install and a few programs?

I've never dual booted before, so I'm not quite sure how easy it is to mess up the process. Can you recommend any tutorials on how to set up a dual-boot configuration on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 Gigs is enough for a [windows-xp install](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/sysreqs/pro.mspx) but not nearly enough for a [win7 install](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/system-requirements.aspx).

But have you considered using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) or [vmware](http://www.vmware.com/) to create a virtual machine instead of dual booting.

Today it's very easy to do and you have access to both environments at the same time.

Comment: Just got it running on VirtualBox, thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

I think all you have to do to dual boot is to have multiple partitions on the drive. If you already have a windows install, you just put in the windows disk, reboot, and when it asks you were to install it, install it to the second partition. When you boot up your computer you will get a DOS like menu asking what version of Microsoft Windows you want to boot to.

Its pretty simple, and hard to mess up.(unless you select the first partition to install to) And as always when messing with installs, please back up your sensitive data.

And 10 gigs might be OK, if you have a few lightweight programs, but I would feel insanely confined in that amount of space. I would at least go for 20 gigs, or have a usb flash drive to write and read data to for extra space.