# Dual boot Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I want to dual boot Windows 8.1 over it so that i can boot into any of these. I have iso file of windows 8.1.

Comment: What are you asking? Whatever you do, back everything up first: Windows installers do not normally respect other operating systems, so you may need to install W8, then restore Ubuntu afterwards using a LiveCD.

Comment: Do you have separate partitions or hard drives? It might be a good idea to install it on a separate drive/partition.

Comment: Just install it like you would any other version of Windows.  Once install repair Grub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing windows to dual-boot](https://superuser.com/questions/178652/installing-windows-to-dual-boot)

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction

This page will explain how to dual boot and install Windows after Linux (Ubuntu, Mint etc) has already been installed.

It is much easier to install Ubuntu after Windows has already been installed, So if starting on a blank slate, **Install Windows first**.

This process was tested with Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 16.04 and Mint 18.3 with Windows 10.

## Back-Up!

Please back-up all important data before continuing. The steps provided worked for a few cases but are not guaranteed to always work. Because partitions are being used and boot menus are being changed, there is a possibility of losing the entire OS or having to try fix partition tables etc.

There are the following back-up options:
1. Save relevant data onto external disk.
2. Get a list of installed programs, this will save time should you need to start from scratch.
3. Clone your entire HDD.

## Before getting started

In order to get everything setup correctly, the first thing is to determine in what BIOS mode the current Linux system was installed (UEFI/EFI OR Legacy). All steps going forward should be done while booted in the correct mode.

Run the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
```

If "BIOS" is printed, legacy is being used. If "UEFI" is printed, UEFI is being used.

***Take note of the mode being used***.

## Booting in correct BIOS mode

Once the BIOS mode of the current Linux system is noted. From this point forward, that mode must be selected when booting onto the USB installation medias.

When starting up the PC, open the boot menu option. Here the various boot options will be listed. On the tested PC, the UEFI option was listed as "UEFI: USBname" and the legacy option was just "USBname".

If there are any issues, some BIOS settings may need to be changed. CSM support may need to be enabled and UEFI/Legacy chosen. Hopefully there should be no issues as the current Linux system would already be using the correct settings.

## What is needed

Both a Linux and Windows USB installation media is needed. **Please ensure that BOTH installation media supports the desired BIOS mode: UEFI or Legacy**.

It is recommended that the Linux installation media is the same version as the currently installed Linux OS. Using different OS versions may cause issues such as differing GRUB versions.

## Step 1: Resizing and create Windows partition.

It is recommended that Linux is used to resize and partition the HDD as Windows may cause issues (Windows partitioning wasn't tested).

It is assumed here that the Linux OS was installed on the whole HDD and there are no existing other partitions.

1. Boot into the **Linux** installation USB in the correct **BIOS mode**.
2. Do not select **Install OS** but rather **Try OS**.
3. Open a program called **GParted**.
4. Select the Linux partition and right-click and select resize/move.
5. Resize the partition **From the back**, resizing from the front may break the boot menu.
6. Resize the partition to the desired size leaving enough free space for a Windows installation.
7. Format the free space to NTFS and give a desired label/name.
8. Apply these changes.
9. Take note of the size of the Linux partition and new Windows partition (For safety but shouldn't be necessary).
10. Switch off PC when changes have been made.

## Step 2: Install Windows

When Windows is installed. The boot loader for Linux will be lost and it will be as if there is no installed Linux system. This will be fixed after the Windows installation is complete.

1. Boot into the **Windows** installation USB in the correct **BIOS mode**.
2. Select the Custom install Windows option.
3. Select the NTFS partition (Should be the correct size that was noted).
4. Click next and Windows should begin to install. See below if there are errors.
5. Follow the rest of the Windows installation steps and allow restarts etc happen until windows is completely up and running.
6. Once Windows is installed and is up and running switch off the PC.

If there is an error message like "Windows cannot be installed to the disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.". This is most likely due to either the BIOS not being setup correctly (enabling UEFI or legacy) or the USB installation media was not booted in the correct BIOS mode (UEFI or Legacy).

## Step 3: Repair the boot menu.

In this final step, The Linux boot menu will be installed instead of Windows. Which should resolve the missing Linux OS.

1. Boot into the **Linux** installation USB in the correct **BIOS mode**.
2. Do not select **Install OS** but rather **Try OS**.
3. Open a terminal and run the following cmds.
4. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
5. Boot-repair should then be installed and open automatically (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
6. Click on recommended repair and follow the prompts.
7. Once completed switch off the PC and remove the USB.
8. Switch the PC back on and if everything was successful, the Linux grub should be displayed and both the Linux and Windows OS's should be available.
9. Test that both OS's start up correctly and can be logged in.

## Step 5: Grub edit

Be careful with this step. After boot-repair, there may be a few more options in the grub boot loader. These options can be removed (not recommended) or the grub order can be changed so that the Linux and Windows OS options are at the top. A default can also be chosen.

To make these changes install Grub-customizer.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer 
grub-customizer
```

In Grub-customizer, the options can be re-ordered by move up/down and options can also be removed. It seems that even after being removed and PC re-started, the grub-customizer can still restore these options.